# Как реализовать различные действия при нажатии одной кнопки несколько раз?

Tags: javascript, android-studio

Подскажите способ, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку происходило действие (менялся текст и картинка в ImageView), a при следующем нажатии на эту же кнопку снова происходило действие (менялся текст и картинка в ImageView) и так по кругу.
Я вижу это примерно так...

```
public void onClick(View AppCompatButton) {
    switch (AppCompatButton.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_left:
            switch (AppCompatButton.гетерТекстаВКнопке()){
                case R.string.level_1_left:
                    svg_main.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blue_level_1);
                    svg_left.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blue_level_2_left);
                    svg_right.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blue_level_2_right);
                    btn_left.setText(R.string.level_2_1);
                    btn_right.setText(R.string.level_2_2);
                    break;
                case R.string.level_2_1:
                    svg_main.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_red_level_2_left);
                    svg_left.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_default);
                    svg_right.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_default);
                    btn_left.setText(R.string.level_3_left);
                    btn_right.setText(R.string.level_4_left);
                    tv.setText(R.string.arrow2);
                    break;
                case R.string.level_3_left:
                    svg_main.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_default);
                    svg_left.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blue_level_1);
                    svg_right.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_red_level_1);
                    btn_left.setText(R.string.level_1_left);
                    btn_right.setText(R.string.level_1_right);
                    tv.setText(R.string.arrow);
                    break;
```

Comment: Не совсем уверен, что это **воспроизводимый** пример...

Comment: Не воспроизводимый? То есть не реализуемый? Любой вариант меня устроит без создания новой кнопки. Можно цвет поменять или любой другой атрибут по которому switch сможет выбирать.

Comment: Не судите строго, я сам учусь всего пару месяцев. Может хоть направление укажите, где инфу искать, если моя задумка совсем тупая?

Comment: Да нет, не воспроизводимый - не есть не реализуемый, вы подробнее можете узнать чем является воспроизводимый пример на StackOveflow (РУ) [в документации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#mainbar) в блоке с "Воспроизводимость", а конкретней про переданный вами пример в пункте 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте обернуть цикл в генератор.
генератор по сути является обычной функцией с некоторыми "но":

```js
function abc(x=1){rerutn ++x;} // функция
abc(); // 2
abc(); // 2
abc(); // 2


function* def(x=1){
  yield ++x;
  yield ++x;
  yield ++x;
  yield ++x;
} // генератор
def(); // 2
def(); // 3
def(); // 4
```

подробнее почитать можно тут:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

```js
function* xyz(){
 var qwe =[
  ['img_name1.jpg', 'text1'],
  ['img_name2.jpg', 'text2'],
  ['img_name3.jpg', 'text3']
 ];
 var i=-1;
 while(qwe[++i]){yield qwe[i];}
}

qwe(); // {[img1, text1], false}
qwe(); // {[img2, text2], false}
qwe(); // {[img3, text3], true}
```

впрочем... можно поступить проще:

```js
var abc = [ // массив со всеми возможными вариантами
['img_m0', 'img_l', 'img_r', 'btn_l', 'btn_r'],
['img_m1', 'img_l', 'img_r', 'btn_l', 'btn_r', 'tv'],
['img_m2', 'img_l', 'img_r', 'btn_l', 'btn_r', 'tv']
];
var i = 0;

function set_lvl(x){ // сама функция с приемом массива
svg_main.setImageResource(x[0]);
svg_left.setImageResource(x[1]);
svg_right.setImageResource(x[2]);
btn_left.setText(x[3]);
btn_right.setText(x[4]);
tv.setText(x[5]);
return;}

set_lvl(abc[i]); // this lvl
set_lvl(abc[++i]); // lvl up
set_lvl(abc[--i]); // lvl down
```

ну как то так...

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение!

```js
public void onClick(View AppCompatButton) {
  switch (AppCompatButton.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_left:
      String text = btn_left.getText().toString();
      switch (text) {
        case "Blue line М1":
          svg_main.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blue_level_1);
          svg_left.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blue_level_2_left);
          svg_right.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blue_level_2_right);
          btn_left.setText(R.string.level_2_1);
          btn_right.setText(R.string.level_2_2);
          break;
        case "red M5 \n above \n Blue line":
          svg_main.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_red_level_2_left);
          svg_left.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_default);
          svg_right.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_default);
          btn_left.setText(R.string.level_3_left);
          btn_right.setText(R.string.level_4_left);
          tv.setText(R.string.arrow2);
          break;
        case "red line M1":
          svg_main.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_default);
          svg_left.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blue_level_1);
          svg_right.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_red_level_1);
          btn_left.setText(R.string.level_1_left);
          btn_right.setText(R.string.level_1_right);
          tv.setText(R.string.arrow);
          break;
      }
      break;

    case R.id.btn_right:
      svg_main.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_red_level_1);
      svg_left.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_red_level_2_left);
      svg_right.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_red_level_2_right);
      btn_left.setText(R.string.level_2_3);
      btn_right.setText(R.string.level_2_4);
      break;


  }

}
```